# Specify the required length of an array passed as parameter

Tags: vb.net, operator-overloading

I have a class that represents a size in percentage on different devices:

```
Public Class Size
    Public Sub New(desktop As Integer, tablet As Integer, mobile As Integer)
        'class logic
    End Sub

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(input As Integer()) As Size
        Return New Size(input(0), input(1), input(2))
    End Operator
End Class
```

The custom operator allows me to create an instance of the class using curly brackets, eg `{100, 75, 50}`. I would like to tell Intellisense that the number of elements in the array must be exactly 3.

Is possible to check the length of `input` at compile time? Thanks

Comment: Consider something like `Dim t = Regex.Matches("12abc456fb432", "[0-9]+").Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(m) CInt(m.Value)).ToArray() : Dim z = CType(t, Size)` - would you expect the compiler to work that out for you? How about for a user-input string?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I want to tell the compiler what I'm expecting, maybe using decorators, maybe something like `Sub test(foo As Integer(3))` so I can tell it that I need 3 elements

Comment: The problem is that it cannot determine what will be passed to it at run-time when it's doing the compilation. Which tells you that maybe that widening operator shouldn't exist.

Comment: @AndrewMorton oh, now I got it. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you requested.  However, if you are using Visual Studio 2017, then you can get minimal Intellisense support by using a Tuple instead of an array.  This will require you to use the Tuple notation;  i.e. use `(,,,)` instead of array notation `{...}`.

```
Public Class Size
    Public Sub New(desktop As Int32, tablet As Int32, mobile As Int32)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(input As (Int32, Int32, Int32)) As Size
        Return New Size(input.Item1, input.Item2, input.Item3)
    End Operator
End Class
```

Example Usage:

```
    Dim sz As Size = (1, 2, 3) ' no error
    sz = (1, 2) ' Error BC30311 Value Of type '(Integer, Integer)' cannot be converted to 'Size'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Type (e.g. `ThreeIntegers`) and use that in the code wherever this constraint exists.

```
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(input As ThreeIntegers) As Size
    Return New Size(input.Element1, input.Element2, input.Element1)
End Operator
```

Of course, your custom type may actually include a defined array (with sensible defaults), so you final call may not look any different than calling an actual array. I tend to use classes instead of types because of some additional flexibility, but the concept is the same.

An example use would be `CType(New ThreeIntegers(10,20,30))`, but given the simplicity of the function, perhaps `New Size(10,20,30)` is all that is needed in each case anyway?

Comment: that would defeat the need of the operator, because I could simply do `New Size(100, 75, 50)`